# How can I change the format of the date in javascript to letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

```
<script id="calendar-list-template" type="text/html">
    <div class="list-row">
        <div class="list-cell">
            {{= ICC.Utils.formatCalendarDate(StartTime) }}
        </div>
</script>
```

here is the function for it:

```
    ICC.Utils.formatDateTime = function(dateTime) {
        return moment.utc(dateTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD H:MM");
    };

ICC.Utils.formatCalendarDate = function (dateTime) {
    return moment.utc(dateTime).calendar();
};
```

It displays:  "2013-03-15"

but I want it to display like this: "15th March 2013"

I have plenty of dates displayed depending on what the user choose from the datepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as `dateTime` is a `Date` object: `moment.utc(dateTime).format("Do MMMM YYYY")`

Comment: Does moment(dateTime).format("Do MMMM YYYY") work? or perhaps try moment("20130315", "YYYYMMDD").format("Do MMMM YYYY")

Comment: What is the type of dateTime?  I tried my suggested answer ``var dateTime = using new Date(2013, 03, 15); moment.utc(dateTime).format("Do MMMM YYYY");`` and it worked for me with version 2.0.0 of momentjs.